# How to use substring operation in liquid json to json transformation?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm using Json to Json transformation using Integration Account in Logic app.

my input is -

```
{"MyText" : "S-12-678"}
```

expected output -

```
{
"First-Data":"678",
"Second-Data":"S-12"
}
```

For above expected output I have created `mydemo.liquid` file like below working good for `First-Data` field but unable to get `"Second-Data":"S-12"` How to achieve it?

```
{
   "First-Data": "{{content.MyText | Split: '-' | Last }}",
   "Second-Data": "{{content.MyText | Split: '-' | First}}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the liquid template below:

```
{% assign arr = content.MyText | Split: "-" %}
{
    "First-Data": "{{arr[2]}}",
    "Second-Data": "{{arr[0]}}-{{arr[1]}}"
}
```

Then the result is what you expected:
[image]

Comment: oh yea got you i was looking for substring expression thanks :)